# Remove feed tabs from record information tab in salesforce community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, configuration

[image]

I have a `Record Information Tabs` component in my Salesforce `community`. I want to remove the `post` and `email` tab from the feed. Is that possible? I'm not able to see anything to configure the component via builder.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove whole feed component, you can do with below setting:-

Double click on record information Tab component and select none instead of feed in tab type option in properties modal. This setting will be applicable to all the record pages not only limited to one object record page.

[image]

If you want to just remove the post and email action and want to see remaining action, you can do that on page layout assigned to community profile.

[image]